# Show a "loading..." div element until list has loaded and then hide the div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an angularJs/firebase list in a mobile app and it takes a couple seconds to load. I wanted to put a simple div there that says "List is loading..." until the list has been loaded with the items.

I know I have to use the ng-hide/ng-show methods but I don't know what expression to use. My list is inside one div, and my "Loading..." text is in another div. How do I tell the "Loading..." div to hide once the List is populated, and not earlier?

I know this isn't the rightway to do it, but its simple since all I have to do is hide one element and show another one. Beats using some form of timeout function which can be so unpredictable sometimes. At least this way, I'm sure the user wont be confused until the list actually loads. They'll actually know that its loading.

I'm using the ionic framework, hence the ion-content tags.

```
<ion-content id="content">
<div class="" ng-hide="loaded">
   "Loading...."
</div>

<ion-list show-delete="data.showDelete" 
show-reorder="data.showReorder" ng-model="loaded">

  <ion-item ng-repeat="client in clients|filter:search |orderBy:'name'"
      item="client"
      href="#/{{client.$id}}" class="item-remove-animate">
      <h2>{{client.name}}</h2>
      <h4>File #: {{client.fileNumber}}</h4>
      <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled"
                          ng-click="removeClient(client)">
      </ion-delete-button>

      <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                          ng-click="edit(client)">
        Edit
      </ion-option-button>

      <ion-option-button class="button-calm"
                          ng-click="share(client)">
        Share
      </ion-option-button>

      <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder=
      "moveItem(client, $fromIndex, $toIndex)">
      </ion-reorder-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: can you share your code pls

Comment: sure hold on, I'll modify my question.

Comment: is the list populated all at once? ng-hide="listName.length > 0", something like that maybe?

Comment: User `ng-show` directive and change the value as `true/false` as per your requirement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hide the loader when the clients array has content

```
<div class="" ng-hide="clients.length > 0">
   "Loading...."
</div>
```

show the list when the clients array has content

```
 <ion-list ng-show="clients.length > 0" show-delete="data.showDelete" 
    show-reorder="data.showReorder" ng-model="loaded">
...
```

Comment: ah...that makes sense! Thanks I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

To hide your div, use attribute

```
<div ng-hide="..." >
```

You'll want to tie this to loading state oft your list.

This depends somewhat on how you get your data, for a crude example you could encapsulate your list like this:

```
var mydata = {};
mydata.values = [];
mydata.loading = true;
mydata.errormsg = "";
```

Then when you retrieve your data, set loading state and/or error message, that way you can also display an error message the same way if something goes wrong, e.g.

```
<div ng-show="mydata.loading">Loading...</div>
<div ng-show="mydata.errormsg != ''">Oh no...</div>
```

Comment: Should I maybe name my list then?

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery BlockUI Plugin [ http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ ] in such scenarios.